# How to Add Something Extra to a Busybox System?

Tags: linux, apt, package-management, busybox, aptitude

So suppose that I have Busybox installed on an embedded device (e.g a router) and need to add something extra to it (a package). Now suppose that now I need to install a package to it besides using the traditional rpm. How would I install a package from the Internet similar to what you get using apt-get or apt? Is there a way or a port to apt-get or similar for Busybox that I can install without having to recompile it for a specific device?

Comment: Busybox's not a distro, it's a software. Compile and install whatever you need.

Comment: busybox is not a distribution, but a program (`sh`, `cat`, etc. compiled into a single binary). Some busybox-based distros do have a form of package management, eg [opkg](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/opkg). But you __cannot__ just install those packages on a different system. Run-of-the-mill router firmwares do not have any possiblity to install extra stuff. Your Q is way too vague -- unless your router is some super secret gear, it won't hurt anybody if you mentioned in your Q the exact model, links to hardware info, the firmware it runs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busybox is not a distro, there is no package manager on it. It also has no shared libraries by default(*), so you have to statically link everything which basically means recompiling everything you want to put on it.

(*) Maybe there are shared libraries on your specific derivative of Busybox, but you won't have the headers for them, so you cannot really use them either.

Comment: @xendroid Whoa! Didn't I meet you somewhere else like SO before?

Comment: @Joe Given your profile, you must have used another id. I remember commenting or answering a similar question not so long ago.